# Site duplicando ícones ao traduzir (Chrome)

Tags: bug, status-intencional, tradução

> O que irei postar aqui e não sei bem se é um bug, pois é uma utilização fora do comum.

Ao acessar os sites da SE em inglês (SOen e PL) e pedir para traduzir o site (botão direto do mouse > traduzir para o português) os ícones da caixa de entrada e realizações (votos) estão duplicando, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu realizei o teste no Google Chrome, e fui informado que que [no firefox também ocorre.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31349379#31349379)

P.S.: Estou postando aqui porque meu inglês não me favorece...

Comment: Mas quem cuida da tradução é o browser, não? Acho que seria um bug do browser.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, por isso que disse que não sei se é bem um bug. Mas antes não ocorria isso

Comment: Só quis postar para fins de conhecimento. Se não for, não vejo problemas também, visto que não me atrapalha em nada.

Comment: Claro, sem problemas

Comment: Me parece coisa do Chrome/Firefox mesmo... Mete um `<font>` na barra do cabeçalho que me parece meio sem propósito. talvez algo no nosso código esteja causando a replicação, mas difícil saber o que é

Comment: A mesma coisa acontece aqui, já faz algum tempo, ao menos não interfere em nada, e sendo uma "tradução bruta" não atrapalha, mas é curioso.